# ObjectDisposedException in ASP.NET Boilerplate manage services

Tags: aspnetboilerplate, objectdisposedexception

I've decided to separate logic from *RoleAppService* to *RoleService*, because I need to use role methods in other app services. By separating logic I can avoid injecting endpoints to other endpoints (e.g. RoleAppService to UserAppService) and possible circular dependency. API is also not visible outside - that's why class inherit from *AbpServiceBase*, no *ApplicationService* (which make service visible in swagger). Unfortunately, when I try to use boilerplate manager classes (e.g. *RoleManager*, *UserManager*) inside *RoleService* method, following exception is thrown:

```
Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'RoleManagerProxy'.
```

With stack trace:

```
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.RoleManager`1.ThrowIfDisposed()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.RoleManager`1.FindByNameAsync(String roleName)
   at Castle.Proxies.Invocations.RoleManager`1_FindByNameAsync.InvokeMethodOnTarget()
   at Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed()
   at Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed()
   at Castle.Proxies.RoleManagerProxy.FindByNameAsync(String roleName)
   at Abp.Authorization.Roles.AbpRoleManager`2.<CheckDuplicateRoleNameAsync>d__48.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Abp.Authorization.Roles.AbpRoleManager`2.<UpdateAsync>d__42.MoveNext() in D:\Github\aspnetboilerplate\src\Abp.ZeroCore\Authorization\Roles\AbpRoleManager.cs:line 283
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at VZero.Roles.RoleService.<Create>d__6.MoveNext() in C:\Users\Marcin\source\repos\translink.vendorforum\Translink.Api\src\VZero.Application\Roles\RoleService.cs:line 42
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at VZero.Roles.RoleService.<CreateOtherDocumentUserRole>d__9.MoveNext() in C:\Users\Marcin\source\repos\translink.vendorforum\Translink.Api\src\VZero.Application\Roles\RoleService.cs:line 94
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at VZero.Roles.RoleService.<GetOtherDocumentRole>d__11.MoveNext() in C:\Users\Marcin\source\repos\translink.vendorforum\Translink.Api\src\VZero.Application\Roles\RoleService.cs:line 107
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at VZero.Roles.RoleService.<UpdateOtherDocumentUserRole>d__10.MoveNext() in C:\Users\Marcin\source\repos\translink.vendorforum\Translink.Api\src\VZero.Application\Roles\RoleService.cs:line 100
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at VZero.Users.UserAppService.<Update>d__20.MoveNext() in C:\Users\Marcin\source\repos\translink.vendorforum\Translink.Api\src\VZero.Application\Users\UserAppService.cs:line 226
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Abp.Threading.InternalAsyncHelper.<AwaitTaskWithPostActionAndFinallyAndGetResult>d__5`1.MoveNext() in D:\Github\aspnetboilerplate\src\Abp\Threading\InternalAsyncHelper.cs:line 120
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at lambda_method(Closure , Object )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ActionMethodExecutor.AwaitableObjectResultExecutor.<Execute>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>d__12.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>d__10.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>d__13.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextExceptionFilterAsync>d__24.MoveNext()
```

Error seems to be related with framework configuration. I've tried to end service name with *AppService*, but it didn't help at all. Service is registered in Windsor Castle framework. What interesting - inside class properly works boilerplate repositories, like *RoleRepository*, *UserReposistory* - unfortunately *RoleManager*/*UserManager* not. Below is the fragment of the the class:

```
public class RoleService : AbpServiceBase, IRoleService
    {
        private readonly RoleManager _roleManager;
        private readonly IRepository<Role> _roleRepository;
        private readonly UserManager _userManager;
        private readonly IRepository<User, long> _userRepository;
        private readonly IPermissionManager _permissionManager;

        public RoleService(RoleManager roleManager, IRepository<Role> roleRepository,
            UserManager userManager, IRepository<User, long> userRepository,
            IPermissionManager permissionManager)
        {
            _roleManager = roleManager;
            _roleRepository = roleRepository;
            _userManager = userManager;
            _userRepository = userRepository;
            _permissionManager = permissionManager;
        }

        public async Task<RoleDto> Create(CreateRoleDto createRoleDto, Action<IdentityResult> checkErrorsMethod)
        {
            var role = ObjectMapper.Map<Role>(createRoleDto);
            role.SetNormalizedName();
            await _roleManager.UpdateAsync(role); // here exception is thrown

            var grantedPermissions = _permissionManager
                .GetAllPermissions()
                .Where(p => createRoleDto.Permissions.Contains(p.Name))
                .ToList();

            await _roleManager.SetGrantedPermissionsAsync(role, grantedPermissions);
            return role.MapTo<RoleDto>();
        }
```

I would be so grateful for any help.

Comment: Add `[UnitOfWork]` attribute.

Comment: It doesn't help in my case, creating new transaction too.

Comment: It seems me that framework forces to use manager services only in endpoints.

Comment: Create a repro project on GitHub.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is no possible - I work on commercial code. I can append some fragments of code if necessary.

Comment: Create a fresh project. You need to provide sufficient code to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you add `[UnitOfWork]` attribute, don't forget to make method `public virtual`